# MVC Inner Join via Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to create a product detail (accommodation details) view based on this controller action:

```
 public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {

        var detail = from cities in _db.Cities
                     join properties in _db.Properties on cities.CityId equals properties.CityId
                     join proplocations in _db.PropLocations on properties.LocationId equals proplocations.LocationId
                     join proptypes in _db.PropTypes on properties.TypeId equals proptypes.TypeId
                     where properties.PropId == id
                     select new
                     {
                         cities.CityName,
                         proptypes.PropType1,
                         proplocations.Location,
                         properties.PropName,
                         properties.PropOwner,
                         properties.PropStars,
                         properties.PropAddress,
                         properties.PropDescription,
                         properties.MaxGuests,
                         properties.PropConditions,
                         properties.PropId

                     };       


        return View(detail.FirstOrDefault());

    }
```

and because is the first time i try to create this i don't know how to solve the scaffolding template model .. 
i get

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType5`11[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'accomm2.Models.Property'.
```

My model here:[image: Model]

My autogen view:

> ```
> @model accomm2.Models.Property
> ```
>
> @{
>       ViewBag.Title = "Detail"; }
>
> ### Detail
>
> Property
>
> ```
> <div class="display-label">CityId</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.CityId</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">TypeId</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.TypeId</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">LocationId</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.LocationId</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropName</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropName</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropOwner</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropOwner</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropStars</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropStars</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropAddress</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropAddress</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropPhone</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropPhone</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropEmail</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropEmail</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropWebsite</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropWebsite</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropDescription</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropDescription</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">MaxGuests</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.MaxGuests</div>
>
> <div class="display-label">PropConditions</div>
> <div class="display-field">@Model.PropConditions</div>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is strongly bound to "accomm2.Models.Property" and your "detail" object is an anonymous object, that's the reason you are getting this message.

For quick test you can try

var prop = new Property {

```
    // Your fields goes here
```

}

return View(prop);

This is just a quick stub code, but ideally this conversion should happen in a separate layer.

Comment: sorry but i'm really new in this where i should add this in the controler ? or i need to create a new model class like: public class detail
    {
    
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string PropType1 { get; set; }
...
    }? thank you

Comment: you can add this code in the controller, just before you are returning the view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use LINQ projection to create a new type instead of supplying the type it is expecting--which is a "Property" object.

Either create a ViewModel and regenerate the page to use that as its strongly-typed type, or change your projection to

select new Model.Property(){
//assign vars
}

Thats my guess

Comment: sorry but i'm really new in this where i should add this in the controler ? or i need to create a new model class like: public class detail { public string CityName { get; set; } public string PropType1 { get; set; } ... }? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your view is defined to take a `Property` as a model.

You're trying to pass it an anonymous type which isn't a `Property`.

You need to either select a `Property` instance or remove the `@model` declaration to make the view take a dynamic model.

Comment: thank you i removed the @model and didn't worked could you explain me how to create and select the property? thank you